# (Unity) Проект несовместим с текущим выпуском Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity3d, visual-studio-2017

Перестал открываться проект Unity/С#, после установки поддержки C++ проектов.
(До этого все работало)
Решение вроде открывается, в самом проекте пишет - "несовместимо".
Переставлял студию и Unity. Сама студия создает C# проекты и работает с ними.
Скрин прилагаю.
[image: Скрин]

Comment: А что если открыть в юнити скрипт и далее при его редактировании  откроется vs ? Так откроется проект?

Comment: Так тоже самое. Уже переставил систему в ноль. Непрофессионально конечно, но проект важнее.

Comment: копии проекта не осталось? Попробуй создать чистый проект и совместить файлы заменив основные файлы хранящие настройки проекта. Сравнить можно проекты с помощью Meld или Merge.

Comment: не, не сохранился